Centering two level-1 variables to create interaction term before multilevel analyses? Thank you
I like to ask for some kind help from the readers here. I have a specific question on creating the interaction term from two level-1 variables before even running the multilevel analyses. Do you

mean-center both variables to zero before multiplying to create the interaction term?
Or multiply the two level-1 variables as they are?

This is especially when I run the multilevel analysis, I will apply group meaning centering on the interaction term.
Thanks in advance!
Regards
Jo

@PeterFlom, are single-level and multi-level models equivalent in this respect? I seem to be getting different interaction results (in terms of coefficient and SE size and p-value) from a multilevel model with a level 1 - level 1 interaction depending on whether I cluster-mean center the predictors vs. use the raw variables. Especially with actual data, the differences are fairly large (with simulated data, they are minor but the results are not identical).

@Sointu Lower-level coefficient estimates (and thus apparent p-values) of predictors included in interactions certainly can change when you center.  Although those coefficients and p-values might differ depending on centering, the predictions from the model shouldn't. If you find a counter-example to my suspicion, please post a question showing it.

@Sointu  I think they are the same. At least, I can't see a reason they are different. When you multiply uncentered variables, you are likely to get colinearity.

Thanks for your comments! @EdM I can't do a mathematical example but I do have data in which the interaction was non-significant with cluster-mean-centered predictors and significant with raw predictors (though with same sign), and other predictor's main effect's sign changed. I'll see if I can put together a question about it.

@Sointu changing the "main effect" of one predictor when you center a predictor interacting with it is to be expected; see the question that this one duplicates. if by "cluster-mean-center" you mean centering observations within different groups to the mean within the corresponding group, then I suppose you might change coefficients for an interaction term. It's when you center all values of a predictor to its grand mean that you are certain to get the same interaction coefficient.

Yeah, I meant cluster-mean centering (which I think OP here also meant). It's always been unclear to me how one should create the interaction term for level 1-level 1 interaction between continuous variables.
